# How to activate logging in plone testing?

Tags: testing, plone, zope

In order to test our Zope based application, we use plone.testing.

It works like a charm, but I cannot find out how to get hold on the logfiles.

I installed SiteErrorLog and via pdb and app.error_log I am able to view the logs. But I want the logs from the test run to be written to the hard disk, as it is common for a normal installation.

In our development and also our production setup, the zope.conf defines where the logfiles should be written to. But as far as I know there is no zope.conf for the plone.testing setup.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: You can directly poke Python `logging` configuration in your test code: http://docs.plone.org/develop/testing/unit_testing.html?highlight=testing#setting-log-level-in-unit-tests

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [testfixtures](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/testfixtures) package; specifically, check [Testing logging](https://pythonhosted.org/testfixtures/logging.html) on the documentation.

If you want to see it working, take a look at the [tests](https://github.com/collective/collective.fingerpointing/tree/master/src/collective/fingerpointing/tests) on the [collective.fingerpointing](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.fingerpointing) package.